# Elastic Search Nest With .NET Slow Scroll Speed

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

Firstly i sorry for my bad english. I have one node in my server.
My index stats below this :

```
{
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 4,
    "successful" : 4,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "_all" : {
    "primaries" : {
      "docs" : {
        "count" : 1951593,
        "deleted" : 0
      },
      "store" : {
        "size_in_bytes" : 594806126,
        "reserved_in_bytes" : 0
      },
      "indexing" : {
        "index_total" : 0,
        "index_time_in_millis" : 0,
        "index_current" : 0,
        "index_failed" : 0,
        "delete_total" : 0,
        "delete_time_in_millis" : 0,
        "delete_current" : 0,
        "noop_update_total" : 0,
        "is_throttled" : false,
        "throttle_time_in_millis" : 0
      },
      "get" : {
        "total" : 0,
        "time_in_millis" : 0,
        "exists_total" : 0,
        "exists_time_in_millis" : 0,
        "missing_total" : 0,
        "missing_time_in_millis" : 0,
        "current" : 0
      },
      "search" : {
        "open_contexts" : 0,
        "query_total" : 5900,
        "query_time_in_millis" : 5539,
        "query_current" : 0,
        "fetch_total" : 1464,
        "fetch_time_in_millis" : 488659,
        "fetch_current" : 0,
        "scroll_total" : 44,
        "scroll_time_in_millis" : 6017059,
        "scroll_current" : 0,
        "suggest_total" : 0,
        "suggest_time_in_millis" : 0,
        "suggest_current" : 0
      },
      "merges" : {
        "current" : 0,
        "current_docs" : 0,
        "current_size_in_bytes" : 0,
        "total" : 0,
        "total_time_in_millis" : 0,
        "total_docs" : 0,
        "total_size_in_bytes" : 0,
        "total_stopped_time_in_millis" : 0,
        "total_throttled_time_in_millis" : 0,
        "total_auto_throttle_in_bytes" : 83886080
      },
      "refresh" : {
        "total" : 8,
        "total_time_in_millis" : 0,
        "external_total" : 8,
        "external_total_time_in_millis" : 0,
        "listeners" : 0
      },
      "flush" : {
        "total" : 4,
        "periodic" : 0,
        "total_time_in_millis" : 0
      },
      "warmer" : {
        "current" : 0,
        "total" : 4,
        "total_time_in_millis" : 0
      },
      "query_cache" : {
        "memory_size_in_bytes" : 0,
        "total_count" : 1668,
        "hit_count" : 0,
        "miss_count" : 1668,
        "cache_size" : 0,
        "cache_count" : 0,
        "evictions" : 0
      },
      "fielddata" : {
        "memory_size_in_bytes" : 0,
        "evictions" : 0
      },
      "completion" : {
        "size_in_bytes" : 0
      },
      "segments" : {
        "count" : 45,
        "memory_in_bytes" : 317076,
        "terms_memory_in_bytes" : 174240,
        "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes" : 22984,
        "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
        "norms_memory_in_bytes" : 25920,
        "points_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
        "doc_values_memory_in_bytes" : 93932,
        "index_writer_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
        "version_map_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
        "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
        "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp" : -1,
        "file_sizes" : { }
      },
      "translog" : {
        "operations" : 0,
        "size_in_bytes" : 220,
        "uncommitted_operations" : 0,
        "uncommitted_size_in_bytes" : 220,
        "earliest_last_modified_age" : 5016454
      },
      "request_cache" : {
        "memory_size_in_bytes" : 0,
        "evictions" : 0,
        "hit_count" : 0,
        "miss_count" : 0
      },
      "recovery" : {
        "current_as_source" : 0,
        "current_as_target" : 0,
        "throttle_time_in_millis" : 0
      }
    }
```

and my mappings below this :

```
{
  "marka_listesi" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "basvuruNo" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "basvuruTarihi" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "durum" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer" : "turkish_analyzer"
        },
        "evrakNo" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "ilanBultenNo" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "ilanBultenTarihi" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "korumaTarihi" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "markaAdi" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer" : "turkish_analyzer"
        },
        "markaID" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        },
        "markaLogoUrl" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "sahip" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer" : "turkish_analyzer"
        },
        "siniflar" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "sonDegisiklik" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "sonIslem" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer" : "turkish_analyzer"
        },
        "sonIslemBaslik" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer" : "turkish_analyzer"
        },
        "sonIslemTarihi" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "tescilBultenNo" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "tescilBultenTarihi" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "tescilNo" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "tescilTarihi" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "tur" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer" : "turkish_analyzer"
        },
        "uTescilNo" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "vekil" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer" : "turkish_analyzer"
        },
        "vekilFirma" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer" : "turkish_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This index have 2 million record but size average 400-500 mb.
I need get all document in index with  dynamic filter and compare in my class method. I'am using scroll.all api from nest but documents coming and adding all documents to my model list very very slow(1 minutes). I seen Maximum cpu percentage for query processing 20%.
I need several second for query complete. This is my nest query :

```
public static List<Models.Model.Sonuc.MarkaListesi>GetDocumentsOnSelectedClasses(string _indexName,ElasticClient _client,string[] _siniflar)
        {

            
            var _docs = new List<Models.Model.Sonuc.MarkaListesi>();

            // number of slices in slice scroll

            var scrollObserver = _client.ScrollAll<Models.Model.Sonuc.MarkaListesi>("1m", 4, s => s
                .MaxDegreeOfParallelism(4)
                .Search(se => se
                    .Index(_indexName)
                    .Query(q => q.Bool(b => b.Filter(fq=>fq.Terms(t=>t.Field("siniflar").Terms(_siniflar)))))
                    .Size(1000)
                )
            );
            var waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            Exception exception = null;

            var scrollAllObserver = new ScrollAllObserver<Models.Model.Sonuc.MarkaListesi>(
                onNext: response =>
                {
        // do something with the documents
        _docs.AddRange(response.SearchResponse.Documents);
                },
                onError: e =>
                {
                    exception = e;
                    waitHandle.Set();
                },
                onCompleted: () => waitHandle.Set()
            );


            scrollObserver.Subscribe(scrollAllObserver);

            waitHandle.WaitOne();

            if (exception != null)
            {
                throw exception;
            }
            return _docs;
            

        }
```

Finally my question is : how can i increase my search speed ?

Comment: The example will buffer _up to_ 2 million instances of `Models.Model.Sonuc.MarkaListesi` in memory, for each call of `GetDocumentsOnSelectedClasses`. This is likely to consume a lot of resources, especially if there are multiple concurrent calls to `GetDocumentsOnSelectedClasses`. Can you explain more about what you'd like to do with the collection, as yielding scroll results as they're returned might be a better approach.

Comment: @RussCam I have single call for this method. I have text input and checkbox input group within form. User can check the checkbox/checkboxes with text input for search. After post, i need to get collection and filter by selected checkboxes. Collection have `markaAdi` field per object. I need compare all `markaAdi` field with searched text(input) and calculate similarity to get text similarity percent with my mixed Levenshtein distance algorithm. After that if **similarity percent > n** for compared text; I need to get object from collection for create new search result index.